# Google web font doesn't load in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-webfonts

I'm developing a website where I using following google web font - Telex. The problem is that it reflects well on chrome and mozilla, but doesn't load in any IE version. I even checked my website in IE tester but it loads website only in IE8 with default browser font, IE6 and IE9 hangs and doesn't load page completely.

To use google web font, I simply took the stylesheet URL from google font page and pasted inside head tag. Then I used provided font-family name in CSS.

Can anyone suggests whats wrong with me?

Thanks!

EDITED -----

Here is the code snippets...

----------HTML CODE ----------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>untitled document</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Telex' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
   <h1 class="contntTxt">WINNER OF THIS MONTH!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

------------CSS Code -----------------

```
.contntTxt{
    font-family: 'Telex', sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
}
```

To add, I've registered copy of Windows 7 with me however windows on my system currently not activated as windows CD not opening. Does this create an issue for IE.

Comment: It should be working because it is technically supported according to "https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Browsers_Supported". Having said that this depends on various factors for e.g. internet connectivity. You should also keep in mind that IE renders fonts in a slightly different way than other browsers. Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: maybe IE tester cant load fonts... hes not 100%.

Comment: Works in IE 10 in all modes, down to IE 5 Quirks Mode. Which version of real IE (not IEtester) have you used? In IE 9 or IE 10, press F12 to enter Developer Tools, then analyze the network traffic. Does the browser send requests and get responses as expected, especially for a font file?

Comment: "IE Tester" is a hack that doesn't always reflect how the real browser behaves. What document mode does F12 show the document to be using? Any errors listed on the CONSOLE tab?